# SET time_zone = '+05:30' is not working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have following query which works fine for me on my localhost and sets current time in database.

```
$query="INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime) VALUES ".
       "(".$_SESSION["user_id"].", NOW());";
```

But when I hosted my website on a US server, it is putting US current time in database, which is undesirable. I want to put Indian current time.

For that I am modifying above query as

```
$query="SET time_zone = '+05:30';INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime) VALUES ".
       "(".$_SESSION["user_id"].", NOW());";
```

But this is not working. Although if I run `SET time_zone = '+05:30';` on mysql directly, it works? Where I should look to resolve it?

Comment: Cannot I fire 2 queries at same time by using mysql_query($query)? Do I need to fire them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change the quotes like that:

```
 $query="INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime) 
         VALUES ( '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', NOW())";
```

SET is for update Not insert.

if you want insert also time_zone

```
 $query="INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime ,time_zone) 
         VALUES ( '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', NOW() ,'+05:30' )";
```

if you already have values you may look for update.

```
 $query="UPDATE mytable SET time_zone = '+05:30' 
         WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'  ";
```

Edit: you cant run two queries in one . you must run both queries

```
$query1="SET time_zone = '+05:30' " ;
$query="INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime) 
         VALUES ( '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', NOW())";
```

Comment: This query is already working fine for me. Why are you using single quote and then double quote around Session['user_id'] as it is integer not string.

Comment: you want to insert time_zone also ?

Comment: no, I just want to set timezone before using NOW in the query so that NOW picks indian current time not US.

Comment: your last update is what I wanted. Before firing my main query which is using NOW, I have to fire SET time_zone query so that NOW can pick updated time zone.

Answer (score 0):

from [**Php manual**](https://www.php.net/mysql-query)

> `mysql_query()` sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
> supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
> associated with the specified `link_identifier`.

so move to [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)  or execute each query separately